# Unable to execute laravel command in ubuntu and Can not find .composer folder in home/<user> directory

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

once I have Error with composer so I uninstalled and delete the .composer folder. Now I again install the composer but .composer folder can not be created. If .composer folder can not be created, I can not run Laravel globally. Please help me with this.[image]

Comment: What happens if you run this command again? `composer global require "laravel/installer"`

Comment: So Laravel is giving you an error?

Comment: i have tried so many times that command

Comment: I can not run laravel command in terminal, I have also set my path variable

Comment: What does it say?

Comment: If I type laravel in terminal, I tells command not found

Comment: What does `which laravel` give you?

Comment: I have install laravel 5.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122466/discussion-between-jefre-n-and-shakyl-mansuri).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create one folder ".composer" in your home directory and then run this command

```
composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

then type laravel in your terminal thing will be work correctly.